# How to pass a Mat array (opencv4android) between two android activities?

Tags: android

I have a problem with passing Mat  (opencv4android) array between two android activities,anyone can help me?

I have solved this problem by writing Mat array to SD-Card as images and read images from SD-Card in another activity.but it has a problem with speed when running on the android phone.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about getting native address of a Mat (getNativeObjAddr), and passing the address to another activity in intent extras. Then just create new Mat array with this address?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Have you done this before? I've never used jsonArray before

Comment: JSONArray a = new JSONArray();
  a.put(new Object());
  String jsonArrayStr = a.toString();
  
  //pass this String into intent extras and read it in another Activity
  
  JSONArray b = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
  for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i) {
   Object o = b.get(i);
   //populate your array here
  }

Comment: "Try putting **it** in a JSONArray" - putting the Array of Mats in a JSONArray, or putting the Mats directly in the JSONArray?

Comment: @Solace How about getting native address of a Mat (getNativeObjAddr), and passing the address to another activity in intent extras. Then just create new Mat array with this address?

Comment: This solution it's not working : 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opencv.core.Mat